# How to use rupee font symbol in flex application

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

I want to display rupee symbol in one label of my project.
I am using "Rupee Foradian" font to display the same.

If this font is install in my pc already, then it works fine.
But if the font is not in machine and embed font directly to the flex, it doesn't display rupee symbol, specially when I make any xml in my flex IDE $ symbol appears but not rupee symbol.

If any one have any idea please help me here or my emailID: skumarvisco@gmail.com

Thanks in advance
Suresh

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with font embedding. You might be missing embedAsCFF or some other property while embedding the font. Could you share how you have embedded the font. If you are loading it at runtime, then you might need to update Style Manager and Font so that it is available in your application and modules(if any).

Hope it helps..